# "You are not authorized to edit this app's settings." when delete facebook app

Tags: facebook

I have a problem with facebook app. When I created a app, I setted an IP with authorized to edit this app. This is Public IP. So now I can't delete this app because I haven't used this IP.How to delete this app. Please help me

Comment: are u created this app in Android?

Comment: No. I created on my desktop.

Comment: Ok, That means you are creating Windows Application, Which language you are using like as c#, You should these kind of information in question